Alter the text size of a modelbuilder label in modelbuilder, ArcGIS Pro
I have an ArcGIS Pro v3.3 model in model builder.  I would like to add some text to describe the steps for the user.  I can add a label to the model but as shown below but the text size is too big.  I would like to reduce the size of the label in the model?
Right clicking does not open any formatting options.  There is no help online that describes this option that I can find.  When the label is selected there is no contextual options on the ribbon available to manipulate this text.
How do I change the text size of a label in model builder?



Select the label so it has the dotty box around it
Click on Diagram tab in ribbon
Change formatting under formatting group


